# How to add left scroll bar using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie with bootstrap. I used SB-Admin to create an admin where I added navigations on the left menu as seen below. However, my problem is when the navigations (links are so many), I cannot display those at the bottom.

May I ask how to add a scroll bar automatically when the navigation list exceeded with the length of the screen?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: try `overflow-y: scroll` when you specify the height.

Comment: Please post the html and css so we can help you with this. `overflow:scroll;` should be added to the wrapper div which I can't specify which unless I can see your codes.

Comment: Hi Daniel A, Thanks a lot it works. Vertical scroll bar is added now. But is this possible that this scrollbar ONLY appears when it reaches the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to my problem, I found the answer itself. By the way, thanks to Daniel for the tip about overflow-y:scroll. In order to automatically appear/disappear that vertical scrollbar, it should be set as:

```
overflow-y:auto
```

This will give an automatic appearance of a scroll bar whenever it reaches a particular height defined in the CSS. This property goes hand with

```
height: 500px;   <<any value of the height
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 500px helps to show the scroll bar but sets the height of the nav bar to a fixed height independent of browser viewport. I solved that in my case by setting height in 'vh'. I used 'vh', as setting height in % was not working.

```css
height: 100vh;
```